# Intelligencia Url Rewrite doesn't work on iis6 - Message Error: Page not found 404

Tags: .net, url, iis-6, url-rewriting

I have the same problem on shared hosting, on local development machine my website works fine with intelligencia url rewrite, on iis6 it doesn't work and i have error "HTTP 404 Page not found" because i think it ingore rewriting rules on my web.config.
intelligencia dll is on directory "bin" of my website

i paste here my rules:

`<rewriter> <rewrite url="~/luoghi_(.+).html" to="~/locs.aspx?id_scat=$1" processing="stop"/> <rewrite url="~/natura_(.+).html" to="~/locs1.aspx?id_scat=$1" processing="stop" /> <rewrite url="~/informazioni_(.+).html" to="~/lists1.aspx?id_scat=$1" processing="stop" />`

--------------web.config url rewrite configuration

`<modules> <remove name="ScriptModule"/> <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/> <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/> </modules>`

`<httpModules> <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/> <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/> </httpModules>`

`<configSections> <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/> <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"> <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"> <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/> <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"> <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/> <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/> <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/> <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/> </sectionGroup> </sectionGroup> </sectionGroup> </configSections>`

Anyone can help me???

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps in

http://csharpgurus.blogspot.com/2011/02/intelligencia-urlrewriter-and-404-page.html.

[Intelligencia UrlRewriter and 404 page not found Error](http://csharpgurus.blogspot.com/2011/02/intelligencia-urlrewriter-and-404-page.html)
 in IIS 5/6 mappings are done only to aspx and other handful extensions you need to pass wildcard extension.